# How to print Hindi text into web page by giving servlet , java and html code

Tags: java, html, servlets, tomcat7

i am using servlet, java and one html code to extract hindi text from following URL : https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%80

i want to display hindi font by servlet code , code is given as :

```
//Extraction1.java //java file
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Extraction1 {

 public String toHtmlString(String url) throws IOException 
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new URL(url).openStream()); sc.hasNext(); )
  sb.append(sc.nextLine()).append('\n');
  return sb.toString();
 }
}
```

MultiParamServlet3.java // servlet file

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MultiParamServlet3 extends HttpServlet
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp) throws          ServletException,IOException
{
  PrintWriter pw=resp.getWriter();

   resp.setContentType("text/html");

   String[] values=req.getParameterValues("habits");

   Extraction1 t=new Extraction1();
   String s=t.toHtmlString(values[0]).replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
   pw.println("<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body>"+s+"</body></html>");

  pw.close(); 
 }
}
```

index.html // html file

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form method="Post" action="MultiParamServlet3">
  <Label> <br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&n bsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter    the URL : </label>
  <input name='habits' id='t2'>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"> 
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

servlet program able to print english text after extraction, but hindi text converted as ????? (question mark).

how to print hindi text into web page by servlet program ?

Comment: You need Unicode, of course.  Do yourself a favor and stop embedding markup in Java code.  Learn about JSP or some other template solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set encoding response.

change `"text/html"` to `"UTF-8"`.

```
resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: i already written as  resp.setCharacterEncoding("text/html");  resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");     but not works

Comment: change it to "UTF-8",

Comment: not works when i used as : resp.setContentType("text/html"); resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

Answer (score -1):

Use StringEscapeUtils class from apache.commons.lang and implement it like:

```
String output=StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(responseMessageString);
```

mathod depends on api version i am using commons.lang 3.3.